# How to handle inheritance class hierarchy in XML serialization using jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have created a simple structure using an inheritance in Java as below

```
public interface DemoSuper {}

public class Child1 implements DemoSuper{ }

public class Child2 implements DemoSuper{ }
```

Then I have a Class DemoContainer which has collection of DemoParent

```
public class DemoContainer{
    ArrayList<DemoSuper> list = new ArrayList<DemoSuper>();
}
```

Now When I am trying to serialize D to xml using jackson I am getting

```
<DemoContainer>
   <DemoSuper></DemoSuper>
   <DemoSuper></DemoSuper>  
</DemoContainer>
```

but I want somewhat like

```
<DemoContainer>
   <Child1></Child1>
   <Child2></Child2>    
</DemoContainer>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is it necessary to have the type of the class encoded in the name of the tag? Or did you just provide a random example.

Comment: No..I need it in my application.